# Dediziertes Verb für Beendigung nach Ablauf einer Frist

Tags: semantics

Gibt es ein dediziertes Verb für die Beendigung nach Ablauf einer Frist?

Beispiel: Ich habe ein Ticket-System, in dem ein Kunde ein Problem schildern kann. Der Hersteller kann mit einem Lösungsvorschlag antworten. Zur Beendigung des Vorgangs muss der Kunde den Lösungsvorschlag akzeptieren. Wenn diese Aktion durch den Kunden ausbleibt, kann der Hersteller das Ticket schließen. Es ist aber kein normales Schließen sondern das Schließen nach Fristverstreichung.

Im Prinzip ist es die Handlung, die die Folge einer konkludenten Handlung ist.

Answer (score 3):

Wenn ich dich richtig verstehe, suchst du nach einer Entsprechung von englisch *to expire*. Man könnte sagen, dass das Ticket *erlischt* oder *verfällt*, oder dass seine Gütligkeit *verstreicht* oder *abläuft*.

Im Kommentar schreibst du:

> Ich suche nach einem aktiven Verb aus Perspektive des Handelnden. Alle vorgeschlagene Verben sind wenig brauchbar:
>
> - *Ich erlösche einen Vorgang*.
> - *Ich verfalle einen Vorgang.*
> - *Ich verstreiche einen Vorgang.*
> - *Ich laufe einen Vorgang ab.*

Eine Lösung ist eine Konstruktion mit *lassen*: Ich *lasse den Vorgang erlöschen*. Oder auch: *Ich markiere den Vorgang als erloschen*.

Comment: Ich suche nach einem aktiven Verb aus Perspektive des Handelnden. Alle vorgeschlagene Verben sind wenig brauchbar: *Ich erlösche einen Vorgang. Ich verfalle einen Vorgang. Ich verstreiche einen Vorgang. Ich laufe einen Vorgang ab.*

Comment: "Wenn ich dich richtig verstehe, suchst du nach einer Entsprechung von englisch to expire." Englisch *to expire* ist zwar aktiv, aber den Vorgang kann eine (andere) Person auch nicht *durchführen*, sondern lediglich das Ticket selbst: "*The ticket expired*" geht, aber "*I expired the ticket*" geht nicht, außer vielleicht in einem Jargon.

Answer (score 0):

Hier sind ein paar Vorschläge, die möglicherweise passen können, wenn ich auch zugestehen muß, daß @JonathanScholbach's Vorschlag mit *lassen* am vernünftigsten erscheint:

> **abbrechen** (wird wahrscheinlich schon anderweitig verwendet)
> **einstellen** (im Sinne von beenden: die Linie wurde eingestellt)
> **dekommissionieren** (naja - besser als nichts)
> **verwaisen** (die Nähe zu "verweisen" ist halt ein Problem)

ansonsten fallen mir nur noch Kolloquialismen ein, die *cum grano salis* zu verstehen sind:

> **schubladisieren**
> **vergessen** (das könnte noch gehen)

Vielleicht könnte man ja statt eines Verbs auch ein Adjektiv verwenden, das man dem Vorgang (Aktion, Ticket, ...) als Eigenschaft hinzufügt:

> **abgelaufen**
> **ungenutzt**
> **unbestätigt**
> **verwaist**